# Find approximating roots to a quaternion polynomial with a naive algorithm

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, quaternions

I am trying to devise a Niave Algorithm to find the roots to Quaternion Polynomials.

I thought I had found a solution in the article [Newton Method in the Context of Quaternion Analysis](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/55629359.pdf), as a Newton Method that works over the Quaternions is exactly what I want. The issue is that, if I understood the method correctly, you need to know the value of the quaternion before you can derive it... at least thats what it looks like in this similar article: [Algorithms for quaternion polynomial root-finding](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0885064X13000162?via%3Dihub). The issue with that is the purpose of this project is to approximate the quaternion roots, which is pointless if I know their exact value.

**Is there an iterative algorithm that will do this? i.e. Find at least one root given a Quaternion Polynomial?**

Note: I would like a algorithm that could be implemented on Mathematica, so it needs to be regularly reproduceable. No... I'm not asking for the code or anything, I just mean it needs to be an actual algorithm not just like a guess/check approach
.
Thanks

Comment: Uh, what makes you think those root-finding algorithms require knowing the root ahead of time?

Comment: Perhaps I am just confused, but in section 9. of the second link all the results they use are done already knowing what the root is... I'm not sure how to do it without it. It is entirely possible I am misunderstanding, In which case an answer to my query would just be an explanation of a theorem in the article but maybe in a way that I can understand. I am an undergrad so I read this through the lense of my own ignorance. In order to guarantee convergence, it seems you actually need the root itself. (If I understood it correctly)

Comment: What is a quaternion polynomial? In all generality it should be $f(q)=a_0+a_1qb_1+a_2qb_2qc_2+a_3qb_3qc_3qd_3+...$ as coefficients and variable do not commute.

Comment: The links I supplied (specifically the second one) rigorously define what a Quaternion polynomial is... I wouldn't be able to explain it to you as well as they can.

Comment: The fact that they don't commute is true... But I don't think I see your point?

Comment: Yes, now that I looked, it is only the very simplified case of only the $a_k$ being coefficients. // There was once a discussion about the quaternion mandelbrot/julia set and what dimension (12?) it has, where the issue was probably due to the restriction to the quasi-complex case. The problem reduces to try to find out what coefficients one can normalize away in a quadratic quaternionic iteration starting from this general form of quadratic polynomial.

Comment: The difference is seemingly that in the reduced case one can, as in the cited paper, generalize results from the complex case. In the general form of some element of $\Bbb H[q]$, one probably can only treat it as a $4\times4$ polynomial system of equations.

Comment: Just because you need to *refer* to a root to *prove* the algorithm converges to it doesn't mean you need the root to *perform* the algorithm - just a sufficiently close seed value, no? That's the same thing with the usual Newton's method for real numbers isn't it?

Comment: Hmmm... I see. That makes more sense. I think part of my issue is determining what suffices as "closeness" in  Quaternion set. How do I know what to pick for my seed?.Do you have an example Quaternion Polynomial with a non-root seed that allows you to find the root? I was accept that as an answer if you can demonstrate an example and how you found the seed w/o knowing the root